# Uncheck a checkbox on click of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a box with multiple checkboxes. I am selecting checkboxes and with that select I am generating a `<span>` **Value  (x)** `</span>` on a different div. Now i want to uncheck the checkbox on click of (x) of that particular checkbox.

Example: [image]

On selecting and deselecting the checkboxes the `<span>` **Value  (x)** `</span>` is coming and going. but the inverse is not happening.

**.reportbox is the class of the tile(checkbox).**
**#compareSection is the area where buttons are kept.**

Code i am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $('.reportBox').click(function() {
        var selected = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(_, el) {
            selectedCheckbox = el.id;
            var element = "<p class='selectedReport'>"+ $(el).val() + "</p>" + "<span onclick='removeReport(this, selectedCheckbox)' class='badge badge-notify close-badge'>x</span>";
            return "<span id='elementPack'>" + element + "</span>"; 
        }).get();
        $("#compareSection").html(selected);
      })

      // this code is for removing the URLs 
      function removeReport(sender, selectedCheckbox) {
        document.getElementById(selectedCheckbox).checked = false;
        var div = sender.parentNode;
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: Where is the code ?

Comment: should i upload it on js fiddle ?

Comment: Wait creating one :)

Comment: Why do you mix jquery and javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.reportBox').click(function() {
        var selected = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(_, el) {
        selectedCheckbox = el.id;
        var element = '<p class="selectedReport">'+ $(el).val() + '</p>' + '<span data-target-box="'+el.id+'" class="badge badge-notify close-badge">x</span>';
        return '<span id="elementPack">' + element + '</span>'; 
    }).get();
    $("#compareSection").html(selected);
  });
  $(document).on('click', 'span[data-target-box]', function(e) {
        $('#'+$(this).data('target-box')).prop('checked', false);
        $(this).remove();
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is working fine :) but removing only the cross, not the capsule shape :( 
how to repair it ?

Comment: `$(this.parentNode).remove(); `
Worked :) Thanks Beeeeeeee

Answer (score 0):

On the line

```
var element = "<p class='selectedReport'>"+ $(el).val() + "</p>" + "<span onclick='removeReport(this, selectedCheckbox)' class='badge badge-notify close-badge'>x</span>";
```

You are using `selectedCheckbox` as a string meaning it will look for the variable when you click it, however the variable was never defined outside the first scope. You probably want to change it to the following:

```
var element = "<p class='selectedReport'>"+ $(el).val() + "</p>" + "<span onclick='removeReport(this, \'"+selectedCheckbox+"\')' class='badge badge-notify close-badge'>x</span>";
```

So that it calls `removeReport(this, 'id_of_element')` with the id as a string which can then be used in `document.getElementById()`.